# Ember.js link-to inside #each block does not render

Tags: ember.js

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <ul>
    {{#each person in controller}}
       <li>{{#link-to 'foo' person}}{{person.firstName}}{{/link-to}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
  <h5>Foo route</h5>
  {{name}}: converted to {{fullName}}
</script>
```

javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return [
          {firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'},
          {firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'Melia'},
          {firstName: 'Formerly Alex', lastName: 'Matchneer'}
      ];
  }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo');
});

App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    // just ignore the params
    return Ember.Object.create({
      name: 'something'
    });
  }
});

App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('name') + ' Jr.';
  }
});
```

I must be doing something wrong, because these `{{#link-to}}`'s are failing. Here's a JSBin. Hesitating to file an issue because this seems like such a simple thing:

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/4777/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route does not allow parameter. Change it to

```
this.resource('foo', { path: '/:person_id'});
```

Comment: I just discovered that this was the problem in my JSBin, but in my actual app, I had to solve the problem by wrapping the `#each` in an `{{#if length}}` block. Not quite sure if I can reproduce yet, because we're using some very old pattern of object proxies that I'm trying to remove right now.